# "StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, internal: Milvus Proxy is not ready yet" - Milvus Vector Search Issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, etcd, faiss, milvus

Milvus was working fine for a while and I wanted to insert data. When I released the collection, milvus crashed with the error "StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, internal: Milvus Proxy is not ready yet". I recreated the docker image several times and even tried to reinstall docker but the error persists .
Details:
Milvus: 2.1.4
ETCD: 3.5.0
minio: RELEASE.2022-03-17T06-34-49Z
System: Ubuntu 22.04LTS
The docker compose file has been taken from: https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/releases/download/v2.1.4/milvus-standalone-docker-compose.yml

[image]

Ran the following command to drop a collection:

```
utility.drop_collection("Data")
```

The expected output is to drop a collection without an error

the actual output:
[drop_collection] retry:4, cost: 0.27s, reason: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, internal: Milvus Proxy is not ready yet. please wait>
[drop_collection] retry:5, cost: 0.81s, reason: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, internal: Milvus Proxy is not ready yet. please wait>
[drop_collection] retry:6, cost: 2.43s, reason: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, internal: Milvus Proxy is not ready yet. please wait>

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the `volumes` dir in root directory you are running the docker compose and compose again

```
sudo docker-compose down
sudo rm -rf  volumes
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: How do you know OP had a volumes directory where they are running docker compose? The docker client and server (engine) may not be on the same machine.